# How to setup a target in Makefile to call 2 targets

Tags: makefile

I try to setup a target in MakeFile to call 2 targets in the same Makefile.

```
build: copy
    copy2

copy:
    cp dir/* ${DIR}

copy2:
    cp dir2/* ${DIR}
```

But when I run `make` in shell, I see it only execute the first target and it said

> make: copy2: No such file or directory make: *** [build] Error 1

I basically change `copy2` to same as `copy` to debug. But I don't see why Make can't find the 2nd target 'copy2'?

Can you please tell me what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The copy2 on line 2 is a command that make will try to execute.  Presumably that command doesn't exist on your system, so make throws the error "copy2" - command not found.

Do this instead:

```
build: target1 target2:
    echo Both targets have been run!

target1:
    echo Running target 1

target2:
    echo Running target 2
```

Output:

```
echo Running target 1
Running target 1
echo Running target 2
Running target 2
echo Both target2 have been run!
Both target2 have been run!
```